# Deployment of simple Play 2.2 application on CloudBees gets intermittent errors

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I am experiencing intermittent errors trying to deploy a simple Play 2.2 application to CloudBees.

My workflow is:

1. Use ClickStart to create a "Hello World" Play 2 app.
2. Use bees app:deploy to overwrite the Hello World app with a distribution of my actual Play 2.2 app.

I have experienced the following problems this morning with this workflow.

### 1. Deployment Error

This error occurred twice today while attempting to deploy my app:

```
% bees app:deploy -a philipmjohnson/surferpedia -t play2 target/universal/surferpedia-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip 

Deploying application philipmjohnson/surferpedia (environment: ):   target/universal/surferpedia-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
Application parameters: {containerType=play2}
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...

ERROR: Server.InternalError - plugin_setup_error: play2 1 Creating application skeleton at /var/genapp/apps/be2f806a
Copying application files to /var/genapp/apps/be2f806a/app
Installing genapp java agent
Writing configuration to /var/genapp/apps/be2f806a/.genapp/control/config
Using JVM at /opt/java7/bin/java
Invalid play dist - unexpected dir count in /var/genapp/apps/be2f806a/app
```

If I re-run the bees app:deploy command again, the deployment succeeds.

### 2. Running application reverts to Hello World

Even more disconcerting, upon (apparently) successfully deploying my Play 2.2 app, after a minute of usage the application reverted back to the Hello World app!

To "fix" the problem, I repeated the bees app:deploy.

### Screencast illustrating the problem

Fortuitously, I encountered both of the problems while creating a screencast for my students on how to deploy their application (called Surferpedia) to CloudBees.  You can see these problems yourself by watching the following 8 minute YouTube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUo9QPqVGeE

Everything goes according to plan until about 5:30 into the video, when these problems start to manifest.

I am wondering if this has something to do with my use of Play 2.2?  Please let me know if there is something I can do to workaround this problem, or if this is a known issue with CloudBees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at this.

Firstly - that error message is from here: https://github.com/cloudweekhec/stack/blob/master/functions#L38

that means that play thinks it is a bad dist - but if you try again, it is ok - which is strange! Are you using sbt to build the dist?

Some steps to remedy:

1) disable the build job - in case anything is triggering it to deploy from source - if you are going to deploy direct - get rid of the build job (that could interfere)

2) try running your upload with --delta false - this will be a slower upload - but will eliminate any zip file confusion.

3) You can switch to using the sbt plugin - this may solve the problem in the short term for you (and still maintain delta uploads): https://github.com/CloudBees-community/sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin (cloudbees-deploy is now cloudbeesDeploy - due to sbt 0.13 changes)

Otherwise - if I can get access to your source code - I would like to try this - setup a test that does this over and over so we can diagnose.

The reverting to hello world is possibly the build job - or it could be failing and rolling back.

Good bug hunting!

Comment: Yes, I'm using the standard "play dist" command to generate the zip file. Looking at Jenkins there was only one build (the original one) so that doesn't appear to be it either.

Comment: If you do a bees app:deploy just after creating the clickstart - the build may still be running.

Comment: I always wait until the modal dialog showing the running build progress bar goes away and the system says, "Your app is ready"(as shown in the video).  Could the build still be running even then?